# Embed youtube video inside page hosted on amazon ec2

Tags: video, amazon-ec2, youtube, dns, ip

I want to embed a youtube video on a page hosted inside a Amazon EC2 instance running apache.

If I try to access that page using the Public DNS address, everything works ok and the video plays.

If I try to access that page using the Elasic IP address, I get a message saying that the content of the video is owned by some company and it's restricted on certain sites.

Why does it work with the public DNS address but not with the Elastic IP? It also works ok when running the site in localhost.

Will the videos work after I link a domain to the elasic IP address?

Regards,

Timo

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the videos work after linking the elastic ip address to a domain.